# Symfony - Form validation error about something is blank although all fields are entered

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I've created a form `IntroUserType` that has two embedded forms `IntroNameType` and `IntroInfoType`.

When I submit the form, with all fields filled, I get

```
string 'ERROR: This value should not be blank.
' (length=39)
```

Here's my forms:

`IntroUserType` :

```
class IntroUserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add("name", new IntroNameType())
            ->add("info", new IntroInfoType())
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            "data_class" => null,
            "cascade_validation" => true
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return "intro_user_type";
    }
}
```

`IntroInfoType` :

```
class IntroInfoType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add("birthday", "birthday")
            ->add("gender", "choice",[
                "expanded" => true,
                "choices" => array(
                    "0" => "Male",
                    "1" => "Female"
                )
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            "data_class" => "Zgh\FEBundle\Entity\UserInfo"
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return "intro_info_type";
    }
}
```

`IntroNameType` :

```
class IntroNameType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add("firstname", "text")
            ->add("lastname", "text")
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            "data_class" => "Zgh\FEBundle\Entity\User"
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return "intro_name_type";
    }
}
```

And here's my view:

```
{{ form_start(form, {"action": url("zgh_fe.user_profile.user_post_intro_edit", {"id": app.user.id})}) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.name.firstname) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.name.firstname, {"attr": {"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "First name"} }) }}
        <div class="validation" style="">{{ form_errors(form.name.firstname) }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.name.lastname) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.name.lastname, {"attr": {"class": "form-control", "placeholder": "Last name"} }) }}
        <div class="validation" style="">{{ form_errors(form.name.lastname) }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.info.birthday) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.info.birthday) }}
        <div class="validation" style="">{{ form_errors(form.info.birthday) }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        {{ form_label(form.info.gender) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.info.gender) }}
        <div class="validation" style="">{{ form_errors(form.info.gender) }}</div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-wide pull-right" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

---

**EDIT**

Here's my entities:

`User` :

```
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $firstname;

    // ..

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $lastname;
```

`UserInfo`:

```
class UserInfo
{
    use BasicInfo;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    protected $birthday;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    protected $gender;

    // ..
```

Comment: Could it be that you are missing one of the entity fields that is not nullable?

Comment: @dmnptr I've edited my question with the entities, Please take a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to output form errors inside the `else` clause of your `$form->isValid()` check:

```
if ($form->isValid())
{
    //........
}
else
{
    die(nl2br($form->getErrorsAsString()));
}
```

This should give you a field name that is blank.

Comment: The problem is that the error doesn't show what it's for. Unlike all other validation errors.

Comment: can I see your setters?